# Get the Current Selected Item of the listview inside CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Inside the view of my customarrayadapter I have a spinner. If one of the items of the spinner is selected it will get the current position of the main Listview. I failed to get the position of the current item on the Listview, where the spinner is active. It will display just position -1.

```
      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        Viewholder v = new Viewholder();
        v.rowView = convertView;
        v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

       v.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Attempt code v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);      
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + listview.getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

[image]

Comment: post your getView method..

Comment: do you want to get the list item position in which spinner is changed right?

Comment: I wanted to get the listview's position not the spinner's item position. See the Toast.

Comment: what i am asking and what you are saying??

Comment: post your getview method

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        Viewholder v = new Viewholder();
        v.rowView = convertView;
        v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

       v.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int arg, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Attempt code v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);      
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: I wanted to get the listview's position not the spinner's item position. See the Toast.

Comment: I don't want to get the position of the spinner but the listview's position where is spinner is current active or focused.

Comment: check now i hv added list view posiion

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final int listview_position=position;

            Viewholder v = new Viewholder();
            v.rowView = convertView;
            v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            v.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //Attempt code v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);      
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + listview_position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bot spinner and array_adapter use same name for positions.. You can also just change the names

```
@Override
      public View getView(final int listview_position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        Viewholder v = new Viewholder();
        v.rowView = convertView;
        v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

       v.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int spinner_position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Attempt code v.spinner = (Spinner)v.rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);      
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + listview_position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: why are you posting multiple answers edit your old answer for better improvement..

Comment: they are actually two different approaches